# Optional Validation in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to know How can I Implement optional validation in asp.net MVC. Like in my **LoginViewModel** I have 3 fields (1) **email**, (2) **username** (3) **password** in View a user can enter either email or password in same input box and if I put **[Required]** on both **email** and **username** fields it do not work. So let me know How Can I handle it in this scenario.

Thanks
Sohaib Javed

Comment: how many input boxes are there in your view? you say a user can enter either email or password in the same input box. so 1 for email/password and 1 for username??

Comment: Why do not you have an input box for each field?

Comment: I have one input box where user can either enter email or username as we see in facebook where user have option to enter email or phone number in the same input box.

Comment: Yes, because an email or username is a valid identifier, a password isn't.

Comment: In your question you have said `a user can enter either email or password in same input box` and in these comments you have said `I have one input box where user can either enter email or username`, which one is it?????

Comment: I would recommend to use separate textbox for both and use Show/Hide on user selection. also write your custom validation attribute to handle this scenario in proper manner.. Let me know if you need further inputs in this direction

Comment: this one is correct: I have one input box where user can either enter email or username. With same actually I wanted to say single inputbox like facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I don't agree that you should have a single input field for a `password` and an `email address`, here's how you might go about performing the validation within the controller for your incoming view model:

```
public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel requestResponseModel)
{ 
    // Has an email or password been entered?
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestResponseModel.EmailOrPassword))
    {
          this.ModelState.AddModelError("EmailOrPassword", "Please enter an email or a password");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            // Is the input a valid email address?
            var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
            return addr.Address == email;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Not valid email, is it a valid password?
            if (System.Text.regularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(requestResponseModel.EmailOrPassword, "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,15}$"))
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError("EmailOrPassword", "Value entered is not a valid email address or password");
            }
        }
    }

    // Did it pass validation?
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid())
    {
        // Register the user here...
    }

    return View(requestResponseModel);
}
```

You could also implement the same code within `Validate()` method of `IValidatableObject` on your view model.  You can have `[Required]` on your model and use this validation within the controller.